# change android volume seek bar Appearance programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

I want to now is it possible to change the android predefined volume seek bar appearance ? if yes how .(the volume seek bar that show changing android device volume ).
thank's in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

The volume bars displayed when you press the volume button are dislpayed by the System, and you cannot control their appearance from your app.

To change it you will have to modify Android at a source level and build your own ROM image.

Answer (score 0):

the changes you want to make are handled by the SystemUI.apk in android, If you are wanting to change this you need to edit the SystemUI.apk here is a great tutorial on how to do that, it's a good place to start short of building your own ROM from source.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2644841